# Spring Security 6.1 returning 403 for non mapped API routes

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security with JWT authorization and recently I was trying to upgrade my Spring Security to the latest version (6.1.1), however for non-mapped API routes I'm getting always 403 Forbidden instead of 404 Not Found, even when setting the Authorization token correctly. I created a JWTFilter that is always called during the Authentication flow. If authenticated successfully it sets the Authentication object inside the context (see code paste below).

I activated TRACE logging and this is the logs when I try to call a path tha wasn't mapped in the SecurityConfig.

```
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4126cd58, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7ecd90ea, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@e25af5a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@34734cf6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5901af8b, org.greenhill.application.config.security.JwtTokenFilter@19098979, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6df7193b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@57640814, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@bad144f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6921fa4d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7a88c97f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7a98b997]] (1/1)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 DEBUG 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /test
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.740+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.741+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.741+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.741+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtTokenFilter (6/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.743+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.greenhill.auth.repository.entity.Worker@6586a89e, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.744+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.744+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.744+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.744+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@61b920f6]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.747+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@61b920f6] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@e8f8395
2023-06-28T19:42:18.748+01:00 DEBUG 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /test
2023-06-28T19:42:18.749+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.752+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4126cd58, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7ecd90ea, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@e25af5a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@34734cf6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5901af8b, org.greenhill.application.config.security.JwtTokenFilter@19098979, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6df7193b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@57640814, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@bad144f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6921fa4d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7a88c97f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7a98b997]] (1/1)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.752+01:00 DEBUG 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-06-28T19:42:18.752+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtTokenFilter (6/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.753+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-06-28T19:42:18.754+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1ef57c0b]]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.755+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1ef57c0b]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@e8f8395
2023-06-28T19:42:18.755+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.755+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-06-28T19:42:18.756+01:00 TRACE 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-06-28T19:42:18.763+01:00 DEBUG 6970 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-06-28T19:42:22.075+01:00  INFO 6970 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-28T19:42:22.080+01:00  INFO 6970 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-28T19:42:22.095+01:00  INFO 6970 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

This is my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthRepository authRepository;
    private final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthRepository authRepository, JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter) {
        this.authRepository = authRepository;
        this.jwtTokenFilter = jwtTokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain jwtFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = username -> authRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found."));
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config)
            throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

This is my JwtTokenFilter class

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (!hasAuthorizationBearer(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = getAccessToken(request);

        if (!jwtTokenUtil.validateAccessToken(token)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        setAuthenticationContext(token, request);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean hasAuthorizationBearer(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(header) || !header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private String getAccessToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = header.split(" ")[1].trim();
        return token;
    }

    private void setAuthenticationContext(String token, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserDetails userDetails = getUserDetails(token);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, null);

        authentication.setDetails(
                new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(String token) {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        String[] jwtSubject = jwtTokenUtil.getSubject(token).split(",");

        worker.setId(UUID.fromString(jwtSubject[0]));
        worker.setEmail(jwtSubject[1]);

        return worker;
    }
}
```

When I call `/auth/sign-in` or `/auth/sign-up` it works perfecly.
Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

From the logs above, apparently Spring Security is executing the same FilterChain twice. On the first time It can authenticate successfully, but the second time it doesn't and then the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` throws the Access Denied

I tried calling my API in a path that is not `/auth/sign-in` or `/auth/sign-up`, and instead of getting 404 I'm always getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: using JWTs as session holders is a security risk, your application can easily be DDoSed as you are doing a database call for every request, your token can be stolen in the browser etc. Dont use JWTs as sessions https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the callout, but this is just a research project, just study purposes

Comment: so for that reason its okey to learn and study bad practices?